# Animate isHighlighted state of an imageView inside a cell of a collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiviewanimationtransition

I am stumbling into an issue with `isHighlighted` state of an imageView inside a cell of a collection view: I cannot manage to animate the transition between 2 images the way I aim for.

Each custom cell of my collection view has 3 views:

1. **an UIImageView** : a background image with highlighted and non    highlighted related .pngs
2. **a second UIImageView** : another image with highlighted and non    highlighted related .pngs as a subview of the previous UIImageView
3. a custom UILabel : a text label

When I touch the cell, both ImageViews instantly move to highlighted state but I would like them to transition to this state instead (a simple CrossDissolve transition)

I have tried 2 different approaches : overriding `isSelected` method in the custom cell class and putting the animation in `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

**Overriding isSelected property**:

```html
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            UIView.transition(with: cellImageView, duration: 1, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                self.cellImageView.setNeedsLayout()
                self.cellImageView.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.cellImageView.isHighlighted = self.isSelected
            })
        }
    }
```

With this way, I get no animation when I click on the cell in the simulator, either when the cell is selected or when it loses it selected state, *except when I **click and hold** a cell*: then I get an animation of the previous cell losing its selected cell (in other words I have the transition of the previous selected imageView from `isHighlighted(true)` to `isHighlighted(false)`).

**didSelectItemAt indexPath Method**

```html
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! SubMenuCell
        UIView.transition(with: cell, duration: 1.0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: 
            cell.setNeedsLayout()
            cell.layoutIfNeeded()
            cell.cellImageView.isHighlighted = cell.isSelected
        })
    }
```

This method does not trigger an animation when the cell is selected but does provide a transition animation when the cell moves from `isSelected(true)` to `isSelected(false)`: in other words, I see the previous selected cell *fading out* and I don't see the selected cell *fading in*.

I'd be grateful for any tips as to why it does not work and how it could be fixed!

Thank you all for the time you took to read and reply!
Best,

Comment: You've implemented `didSelectItemAt`. But what about [`didDeselectItemAt`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618035-collectionview)?

Comment: Thanks @Rob for taking the time! I would assume implementing `didDeselectItemAt` would trigger the opposite result that I want, which is already what I have unfortunately. But I did try to implement what you suggest, with and without `didSelectItemAt` method as well, and in both cases, there were no animations at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the guys to have taken the time to think about my question.
By investigating further, I decided to check how and when 3 events, namely `cell.isHighlighted`, `cell.isSelected` and `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` where triggered and I found some pretty interesting things actually. Let me sum it up:

**When you touch a cell (cell1) in a collection view, it appears the following events occur:**

1. `cell1.isHightlighted` is set to `true`
2. `cell1.isHightlighted` is set to `false`
3. `cell1.isSelected` is set to `true`, which calls back `cell1.isHighlighted` property
4. and lastly `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` method is called

**Now when you touch another cell (cell2) in the collection View, the following events occur:**

1. `cell2.isHighlighted` is set to `true`
2. `cell1.isSelected` is set to `false`, which calls back `cell1.isHightlighted` property
3. `cell2.isHighlighted` is set to `false`
4. `cell1.isSelected` is set to `false` again (!)
5. `cell2.isSelected` is set to `true`, which calls back `cell2.isHighlighted` property
6. and again lastly `collectionView(_ collectionView:
       UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` method is
       called

With that in mind, I came to the conclusion that to run a transition animation on `isHighlighted` state in the collection view method will never work as intended since the property has already been set prior to reach the method.

One solution to obtain both animations (`isHighlighted` `true` and `false`) that I have found is to act on the property observers of `isHighlighted` and `isSelected` of my custom collection view cell, as follow:

```html
override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        willSet {
            if newValue == true {
                UIView.transition(with: cellImageView, duration: 1.0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                    self.cellImageView.isHighlighted = newValue
                })
            }
        }
    }
    
 override var isSelected: Bool {
        willSet {
            if newValue == false {
                UIView.transition(with: cellImageView, duration: 1.0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                    self.cellImageView.isHighlighted = newValue
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope it helps, and thanks again to all of you whom have spent some time trying to figuring it out!
If anyone finds a more elegant solution, do not hesitate to post it!!!
Best,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced but I think you might also want to override;

```
override func setSelected(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool)
```

In your `UICollectionViewCell` as well as the `isSelected` property and therefore your animation code in `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)`.

*Note that there is also a difference between `isHighlighted` and `isSelected`, you said `isHighlighted` in your question, but leveraged `isSelected` in your implementation.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel!  The problem with calling the methods that I have found is explained in my answer: the order with which the events are called...